# How to kill the session from Unique sessionID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have count the number of online user to the web server. I have created the username & assign the password to individual computer then using this user name user can access the main page & after login user I have add the username, session ID, IP address in datatable. If i user already connected from another computer then same user access the information from another computer then user first disconnect the already connected from current computer using kill the session from sessionID . then another computer functionality automatically disabled to user then user can start the new session for current computer.

How to kill the session from Unique sessionID & disabled the all functionality of the another computer user?

Comment: You cannot use Session for this as sessions are limited to only a client's request
But Your problem is dealing with multiple clients so session seems inappropriate for that reason.
some database storing, retrieving would work here..

Answer (score 0):

i would try it this way :
On login generate a random string, write it into a session variable and store it in database, then in ur page compare this values against each other to verify user access. this way a user can be logged on only once.

Comment: ur english is quite bad, can u try to explain what exactly u mean ? ur reply doesnt make much sense. ur question is also very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
Session.Remove("keyOfSession");
```

Comment: if we used this for remove the session of the particular computer then it will disabled the web page fuctionality automatically

Comment: im pretty sure he wants to kill the session, not a session variable

Answer (score 0):

For example you could have a property object in your ApplicationInstance, such as a Dictionary :

- Key would be the userId
- Value would be a list of KeyValuePair where

  - KVP Key would be user IP
  - KVP Value would be a WeakReference to a session object

At the end of a Session_Start, you insert an item in your Dictionary=>List for the corresponding user and IP holding a WeakReference to the Session object.
Then, you also End() all other not null, weak referenced, Session objects for this user and other IPs (be aware that some users access the internet through dynamic proxies that may change between requests)